# FOSElasticaBundle Update Nested Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, foselasticabundle

Why I have empty nested entity? I have index talent. In database talent have nested user and when Now, when I update or create a talent, it not will be updated as a nested object in ElasticSearch and I don't understand why ?

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default:
      host: %elastica_host%
      port: %elastica_port%
      headers: { Authorization: Basic %elastica_auth_header% }

indexes:
    profile:
        finder: ~
        types:
             talent:
                mappings:
                    id:
                       type: integer
                    slug:
                       type: string
                    description:
                       type: string
                    user:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                             id: ~
                             username:
                                type: string
```

I search and find about override Listener `postPersist`, `postUpdate`, and `preRemove`

```
fos_elastica.listener.talent:
    class: Artel\SiteBundle\EventListener\ElasticaCourseListener
    arguments:
        - @fos_elastica.object_persister.user.user
        - ['postPersist', 'postUpdate', 'preRemove']
        - @fos_elastica.indexable
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, ['@service_container', @fos_elastica.object_persister.profile.talent ] ]
    tags:
        - { name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber' }
```

My own listener `Artel\SiteBundle\EventListener\ElasticaCourseListener` then looks like this:

```
<?php

    namespace Artel\SiteBundle\EventListener;

    use Doctrine\Common\EventArgs;
    use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\Listener as BaseListener;
    use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
    use Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer;

    class ElasticaCourseListener extends BaseListener
    {
        private $container;
        private $objectPersisterSession;

        public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container, ObjectPersister $objectPersisterSession)
        {
            $this->container = $container;
            $this->objectPersisterSession = $objectPersisterSession;
        }

        public function postUpdate(EventArgs $args)
        {
            $entity = $args->getEntity();

            if ($entity instanceof Developer) {
                $this->scheduledForUpdate[] = $entity;
                foreach ($entity->getUser() as $session) {
                    $this->objectPersisterSession->replaceOne($session);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I have error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>       Runtime Notice: Declaration of Artel\SiteBundle\EventListener\ElasticaCourseListener::postUpdate() should be compatible with FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\Listener::postUpdate(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)

Help please

Answer (score 0):

You have to be using this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
```

Forget that one:

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventArgs;
```

There are some updates in the Doctrine ;)

Comment: You must use ` use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;;`  in Symfony > 5